# UseSubmitBehavior=False not working with OnClientClick when webform is based on a Master Page

Tags: asp.net, onclientclick

I'm writing an admin page where I have a textbox for user name and a refresh button which shows user details when clicked. Among other controls, I have a 'remove user' button to delete the user. I have javascript code to get confirmation before attempting this.
Because I do not want this Remove User button to have submit behavior, I have set UseSubmitBehavior=False. However, this caused the server side event to not get fired. So I wrote a small client side function to explicitly call __doPostBack.

The final code works, but only on pages that are *not* based off of a master page or nested master pages. Sadly all my web pages are based off of master pages.
Wondering if I'm missing something or if there is a way around? I've just started asp.net so please excuse any obvious mistakes.

Many thanks in advance.

### Code Sample:

Following code works (webform with no master page)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm_with_NoMasterPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm_with_NoMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function GetConfirmation(btn, msg) {
                    if (confirm(msg)) {
                        __doPostBack(btn.id, '');
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            </script>

            <asp:Button ID="btnRemoveUser" runat="server" Text="Remove User" OnClick="btnRemoveUser_Click" 
                OnClientClick="return GetConfirmation(btnRemoveUser, 'Really remove?');"
                UseSubmitBehavior="false"
                Height="37px" Width="230px" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm_with_NoMasterPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnRemoveUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // put a breakpoint here and see if it is hit.
            int x = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Following does not work (same fragment but in a Webform based on masterpage):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm_WITH_MasterPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm_WITH_MasterPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function GetConfirmation(btn, msg) {
                    if (confirm(msg)) {
                        __doPostBack(btn.id, '');
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            </script>

            <asp:Button ID="btnRemoveUser" runat="server" Text="Remove User" OnClick="btnRemoveUser_Click" 
                OnClientClick="return GetConfirmation(btnRemoveUser, 'Really remove?');"
                UseSubmitBehavior="false"
                Height="37px" Width="230px" />

</asp:Content>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm_WITH_MasterPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnRemoveUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // put a breakpoint here and see if it is hit
            int z = 0;
        }
    }
}
```